# Maximum from dictionary but not equal to 1

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I need to find maximum value from dictionary but the value must not be equals to 1.

This is my code. I am able to get the maximum value but I dont need the value 1.

```
maximum_value = max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)
```

is there any expression or something that I can include here ?

This is my dictionary -

```
{'diagnosis': 0.9210526315789473, 'radius_mean': 0.8421052631578947, 'smoothness_mean': 1.0, 'compactness_mean': 1.0, 'concavity_mean': 1.0, 'concave points_mean': 1.0, 'symmetry_mean': 1.0, 'fractal_dimension_mean': 1.0, 'radius_se': 0.9473684210526315, 'texture_se': 0.5263157894736842, 'perimeter_se': 0.4824561403508772, 'smoothness_se': 1.0, 'compactness_se': 1.0, 'concavity_se': 1.0, 'concave points_se': 1.0, 'symmetry_se': 1.0, 'fractal_dimension_se': 1.0, 'radius_worst': 0.8157894736842105, 'smoothness_worst': 1.0, 'compactness_worst': 0.9912280701754386, 'concavity_worst': 0.9824561403508771, 'concave points_worst': 1.0, 'symmetry_worst': 1.0, 'fractal_dimension_worst': 1.0}
```

I dont need those values with 1.0 in them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What value do you want in `maximum_value` if the highest value is 1? The next highest after that? Can you provide some more context on the data in your dictionary?

Comment: please give a reproductible example

Comment: are you interested in only the value or do you actually want the key (which is what your given code returns)

Comment: You can use a custom function as `key` and instead of 1, return some small value (0?) and return everything else normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two easy ways to do this. First, you can use numpys infinity value and return this whenever your value is 1, like:

```
import numpy as np
stats = {'a':1, 'b':0.7, 'c': -1}
maximum_value = max(stats.values(), key=lambda x: x if x != 1 else -np.inf )
```

Otherwise, you could also filter the dictionary to exclude the value one before taking the maximum, that is

```
maximum_value = max(filter(lambda x: x !=1, stats.values()))
```

If, as your given code does, you want to know the key instead, you can use the filtered dictionary in place of what you did before, as in

```
maximum_key =  max(filter(lambda x: stats[x] !=1, stats.keys()), key = stats.get)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a conditional slice and take max from that

```
maximum_value = max([i for i in dictionary.values() if i != 0])
```